# Java BorderLayout: How to set Preferred size of components

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I Have a Frame with two panels, one named ScreenPanel and one named MenuPanel, Both have Border Layout Manager. ScreenPanel is the Content Panel for the JFrame. Menu Panel is on the WEST of the ScreenPanel. However, when I run, the width of the MenuPanel is too small, I tried adding setSize(); to MainPanel and all of its components, but that didn't work, is there a way I can set the size of the MenuPanel in BorderLayout?

MenuPanel:

```
DefaultListModel<String> MenuModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> MenuList = new JList<>(MenuModel);
JLabel MenuLabel = new JLabel();
MenuPanel(){
    setBackground(new Color(0,168,243));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    MenuList.setBackground(new Color(0,200,250));
    MenuList.setForeground(new Color(80,80,80));
    MenuList.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20));

    MenuModel.addElement("Page 1");
    MenuModel.addElement("Page 2");
    MenuModel.addElement("Page 3");
    MenuModel.addElement("Page 4");
    MenuModel.addElement("Page 5");

    MenuLabel.setText("Menu");
    MenuLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,50));
    MenuLabel.setForeground(new Color(50,50,50));

    add(MenuList,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(MenuLabel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

ScreenPanel:

```
public class ScreenPanel extends JPanel{
     ScreenPanel(){
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
         add(new MenuPanel(),BorderLayout.WEST);
     }
 }
```

Frame:

```
 public class ScreenFrame extends JFrame{
     ScreenFrame(){
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
         setContentPane(new ScreenPanel());
        setTitle("Random Project");
     }
 }
```

Main Method:

```
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         ScreenFrame screen = new ScreenFrame();
         screen.pack();
         screen.setVisible(true);
     }
 }
```

Expectation:
[image]

Reality:
[image]

Comment: Why did you delete your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718018/free-accordion-in-java-swing? If the suggestion helped you then they may benefit others who search the forum.

Comment: Actually, I am new to Stack Overflow, so stack overflow suggested me to delete the question, so I thought I should, can I revive it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java conventions.

> I tried adding setSize()

Don't attempt to play with the size. It is the responsibility of the layout manager to determine the size and location of each component.

You should also not attempt to "set" the preferred size of a component. All Swing components determine their own preferred size based on the properties of the component.

You can affect the preferred size calculation of components by changing the properties of the component.

For all components you could use:

1. `setFont(..)` - to make the text larger
2. `setBorder( new EmptyBorder(...) )` - to give extra space around the 4 borders. The border can be set for individual components or on the JPanel for all components added to the panel.

In addition, for the JList you can use:

1. `setPrototypeCellValue( "Page 0000" )` - to calculate a larger preferred width based on the text you specify

Read the API you may find other properties you can change.

Comment: can you please tell me what parameters do we need in Component.setBorder.(new EmotyBorder(...?....));

Comment: @meetprakashshah,  Read the API!!! You can't program without using the API. Also your question was about **setting the preferred size of components**. This answers that question by showing your various options on how to do this. This answer applies whether you decide to use a JList of JButtons, so in fact it answer the question you asked. Why wasn't it "accepted".

Comment: Well your answer is perfect @camickr, I don't have any problem, in fact, I am really thankful for all your help so far

Comment: @meetprakashshah *Well your answer is perfect* - and it was answered 15 minutes after you asked the question and yet you didn't "accept" the answer even though it directly answered your question. The other answer has nothing to do adjusting the preferred size of components.

Comment: Well after seeing your answer, I was not able to figure out what am I supposed to do, so I needed more clarification, and so I asked you in the comments. I have no idea why are you saying I didn't accept your answer, I have tick marked it.

Comment: There are two answers to your question. You did not accept my answer. You accepted the other answer.  You asked what the parameters are for the EmptyBorder. I gave you an answer. The answer is to read the API. What part of the EmptyBorder constructor do you not understand?  Or the other option is to search the site for examples that use the `EmptyBorder` class.

Comment: Ohk, I now came to know that I can not accept more than one answer. what happened is that I accepted your answer than I accepted the other answer, I didn't realize that your answer will get "not accepted".

Answer (score 0):

A JList is not the right control for what you’re doing.  A JList is for a variable number of data items, and is always supposed to be placed in a JScrollPane.

You probably want a set of JButtons, placed in a JPanel that uses a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html) configured to have only one column.  GridLayout will force all of its children to be large enough to fill its corresponding container.

```
MenuPanel() {
    setBackground(new Color(0,168,243));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel menuList = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    menuList.setBackground(new Color(0,200,250));
    menuList.setForeground(new Color(80,80,80));

    Font menuFont = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20);

    JButton menuButton;

    menuButton = new JButton("Page 1");
    menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
    menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    menuList.add(menuButton);

    menuButton = new JButton("Page 2");
    menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
    menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    menuList.add(menuButton);

    menuButton = new JButton("Page 3");
    menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
    menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    menuList.add(menuButton);

    menuButton = new JButton("Page 4");
    menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
    menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    menuList.add(menuButton);

    menuButton = new JButton("Page 5");
    menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
    menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    menuList.add(menuButton);

    JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel();
    menuLabel.setText("Menu");
    menuLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,50));
    menuLabel.setForeground(new Color(50,50,50));
    menuLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 48));

    add(menuList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(menuLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Of course, using a loop can make the above code a lot shorter:

```
MenuPanel() {
    setBackground(new Color(0,168,243));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel menuList = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    menuList.setBackground(new Color(0,200,250));
    menuList.setForeground(new Color(80,80,80));

    Font menuFont = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20);

    String[] pageLabels = {
        "Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3", "Page 4", "Page 5",
    };

    JButton menuButton;

    for (String pageLabel : pageLabels) {
        menuButton = new JButton(pageLabel);
        menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
        menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
        menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        menuList.add(menuButton);
    }

    JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel();
    menuLabel.setText("Menu");
    menuLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,50));
    menuLabel.setForeground(new Color(50,50,50));
    menuLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 48));

    add(menuList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(menuLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

If your button labels are really Page 1 through Page 5, you can just use a numeric loop:

```
MenuPanel() {
    setBackground(new Color(0,168,243));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel menuList = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    menuList.setBackground(new Color(0,200,250));
    menuList.setForeground(new Color(80,80,80));

    Font menuFont = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,20);

    JButton menuButton;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        menuButton = new JButton("Page " + i);
        menuButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
        menuButton.setFont(menuFont);
        menuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        menuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        menuList.add(menuButton);
    }

    JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel();
    menuLabel.setText("Menu");
    menuLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
    menuLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,50));
    menuLabel.setForeground(new Color(50,50,50));
    menuLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 48));

    add(menuList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(menuLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
```

Note that in Java, variable names always start with a lowercase letter (unless they are static final fields, in which case the name should be in ALL_CAPS).